# AngularJS: how to get the coordinates of a selected text in the page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

Working with an AngularJS application,
I have an array in this format:

```
reportPages = [
{0: [
0:
1:
2:
3:
]},

{1: [
0:
1:
2:
3:
]},

{2: [
0:
1:
2:
3:
]}, 

{3: [
0:
1:
2:
3:
]}
...
]
```

So As you can see I call this array reportPages and each element (each page) has several lines.

When I get this array, I print the report (pages and their lines) in the html and the user sees a report in front of him/her.

Now if the user choose a text in the report with his/her mouse, I want to grab that text and find it in the reportPages array. **The trick here is maybe that selectedText is found in many pages and lines. So I want that specific one the user selected (in that page and that line and that index). How I can get the coordinate of that one and in my reportPages array find it.**

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your array syntax, judging by your code is not good.

Comment: can you clarify more, what you mean?

Comment: When declaring array this 0: [0: 1: 2: 3: ], will give you error. This is not proper syntax

Comment: ok, you mean I've missed the {}. I've added those.